# Flink HA State backend

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to configure Flink 1.2.0 for an HA setup and there I have to set a parameter called state backend. I have set this parameter to rocksdb previously but then read the documentation which says for HA only filesystem is available. Is this true ? (only filesystem state backend is supported for HA setups and no rocksdb is available?) or is this referring to a different (zookeeper specific) state backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is misleading on this point. Both RocksDB and the FsStateBackend checkpoint to a filesystem using the same mechanism, and a reference is kept in ZooKeeper. So it's actually independent of the backend being used.